# Is it possible to search for a phrase in opengrok containing curly brackets?

Tags: opengrok

I have tried using something like "struct a {" and "struct a {" to look for the declaration of "a". But it seems opengrok just ignores the curly brackets. Is there a way to search for the phrase "struct a {"?

Answer (score 3):

Grok supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. 
The current list of special characters are

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

To escape these character use the \ before the character. 
For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query: \(1\+1\)\:2
```

Comment: The backspace does not appear to work as an escape character. I'm trying to search our codebase for any instances of SELECT *,   so i search using:   "SELECT \*".  This query returns the same number of results as the "SELECT" query.  The backslash was ignored...

Comment: How about ">" as in `->` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to search with "struct a {" (with quotes)

Answer (score 0):

From OpenGrok documentation:

**Escaping special characters:**

Opengrok supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. Current special characters are:

+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query: (1+1):2

**NOTE** on analyzers: Indexed words are made up of Alpha-Numeric and Underscore characters. One letter words are usually not indexed as symbols!
Most other characters (including single and double quotes) are treated as "spaces/whitespace" (so even if you escape them, they will not be found, since most analyzers ignore them).

The exceptions are: @ $ % ^ & = ? . : which are mostly indexed as separate words.
Because some of them are part of the query syntax, they must be escaped with a reverse slash as noted above.

So searching for +1 or + 1 will both find +1 and + 1.

**Valid FIELDs are**

**full**

> Search through all text tokens (words,strings,identifiers,numbers) in
> index.

**defs**

> Only finds symbol definitions (where e.g. a variable (function, ...)
> is defined).

**refs**

> Only finds symbols (e.g. methods, classes, functions, variables).

**path**

> path of the source file (no need to use dividers, or if, then use "/"
>
> - Windows users, "" is an escape key in Lucene query syntax! Please don't use "", or replace it with "/"). Also note that if you want
>   just exact path, enclose it in "", e.g. "src/mypath", otherwise
>   dividers will be removed and you get more hits.

**hist**

> History log comments.

**type**

> Type of analyzer used to scope down to certain file types (e.g. just C
> sources). Current mappings: [ada=Ada, asm=Asm, bzip2=Bzip(2), c=C,
> clojure=Clojure, csharp=C#, cxx=C++, eiffel=Eiffel, elf=ELF,
> erlang=Erlang, file=Image file, fortran=Fortran, golang=Golang,
> gzip=GZIP, haskell=Haskell, jar=Jar, java=Java, javaclass=Java class,
> javascript=JavaScript, json=Json, kotlin=Kotlin, lisp=Lisp, lua=Lua,
> mandoc=Mandoc, pascal=Pascal, perl=Perl, php=PHP, plain=Plain Text,
> plsql=PL/SQL, powershell=PowerShell script, python=Python, ruby=Ruby,
> rust=Rust, scala=Scala, sh=Shell script, sql=SQL, swift=Swift,
> tar=Tar, tcl=Tcl, troff=Troff, typescript=TypeScript,
> uuencode=UUEncoded, vb=Visual Basic, verilog=Verilog, xml=XML,
> zip=Zip] The term (phrases) can be boosted (making it more relevant)
> using a caret ^ , e.g. help^4 opengrok - will make term help boosted

Opengrok search is powered by [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), for more detail on query syntax refer to [Lucene docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description).